# Using chart and tooltip

Tags: vb.net, graph, tooltip

I'm in internship for a month and i'm using  Chart and tooltip :

```
Dim serie As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series = mydata.getSeries()
For i = 0 To serie.Points.Count - 1
    For Each ser As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series In Chart1.Series
                        ser.Points.Add(serie.Points(i))
       Next
Next
'Chart1.Series(1).LabelToolTip = "why"
```

Points I add to ser has tooltip but when i launch the app, i can't see tooltip.
If i uncomment the last line, i can see the tooltip.
I can put anything to replace "why" but i must put something or i couldn't see tooltip of point. So atm my code works but i dont understand why I need this line

```
Chart1.Series(1).LabelToolTip = "why"
```

I would like to understand my code ^^

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I think you're asking this: "Why is the LabelToolTip property needed in order to display a tooltip?" Is that right?

Comment: Yes,  it's exactly why i wonder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your question now.

The reason why you're not seeing your tooltips is because each point has to be given a value for its LabelToolTip property.

So here's what you could do:

```
Dim serie As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series = mydata.getSeries()
    For i = 0 To serie.Points.Count - 1
        For Each ser As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series In Chart1.Series
                            serie.Points(i).LabelToolTip = "What ever you want"
                            ser.Points.Add(serie.Points(i))
           Next
    Next
```

Now, each point will have a LabelToolTip. Previously, you weren't setting the tooltips, and they will not display until they are set.

Comment: Ok, now i understand my problem, thanks, but i still dont know why vb.net want a labeltooltip when it's not necessary